# How to change Table rate shipping method title text if cart amount is above 100 Magento 2?

Tags: shipping-methods, checkout-page, table-rates, magento2.3.5-p2

I have added custom text to display with Table rate shipping method title.

```
<span data-bind="visible: method.carrier_code == 'tablerate'">
            <span class="shippingtext">Same Day Delivery - Only AED <each args="element.getRegion('price')" render="" /> additional charge</span>
       </span>
```

How can I add if else condition to show different text according to cart amount?

For example:

1. Cart amount is below AED 100 then Title will be "Same Day Delivery - Only AED 30 additional charge"
2. Cart amount is above AED 100 then Title will be "Same Day Delivery - Only AED 10 additional charge"

Comment: in which file you added code ? methods.html?

Comment: I have added this code in the file: Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping-address/shipping-method-item.html